# Expected Inflation and its results

Tags: inflation

I was reading a macroeconomics textbook and found two statements which seem kind of contradictory so I wish to ask how to correctly interpret this.

1. “When expected inflation is high, people increase their savings (such as buying bonds) due to the high nominal interest rate.”
2. “When expected inflation is high, people decrase their savings and increase their consumption because they expect that prices will become high in the future.”

If we look at the loanable funds market, the first statement will be represented by the rightward shift of the Savings curve (Supply of loanable funds), and the second statement will be represented by the leftward shift of the Savings curve (since increase in consumption means the same thing as decrease in savings as seen in the equation Y income = C consumption + S savings).

Thus the first statement and the second shows us completely opposite results, despite the fact that they come from the same stimulus - the rise of expected inflation.

So how should I understand this? what happens to the loanable funds market in the end (does the Savings curve shift rightward or leftward?) I would appreciate a detailed explanation :)

Comment: These are assertions and would need to be tested empirically.  For example, there is FRED data since 2003 on [Personal savings](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=oQeF) and [Inflation expectations](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=m1iL) and [Interest rates](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=n5OS).

Comment: Income effect and substitution effect---look them up in any principles of microeconomics textbook.

Comment: Not a fan of such arguments, but was there reference to real interest rates? The macro models I’m familiar with are more affected by the real rate.